# How can I do QTableWidget format like Excel file format?

Tags: excel, qt, qtablewidget

[excel format picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKEVI.jpg)

I want to show this excel file in my application. I use QTableWidget but I don't know how to format it. Can I do this using QTableWidget? Or which component I should use?

Comment: There is nothing in Qt that can load an Excel file and display it. You should use Excel itself, as an ActiveX control. Use QtActiveX for that.

Comment: I'm using QAxObject to read excel file. But I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Just show the document window for the file you've loaded. Excel has all the APIs you need for that. Use `QAxWidget` for that, of course.

Comment: [this is cool page](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format)  with list of possible solutions (most are commercial).